# Angular 5 - GAE flex environment deployment

Tags: angular5, gcloud, bitbucket-pipelines

We use bitbucket pipeline for our angular 5 to deploy our code to GAE. We are ending up with the following exception. We use bitbucket pipelines the the CI/CD

THis is the pipeline code

```
    image: node:9.11.1
     pipelines:

      custom:

       default:

         - step:

           script: 

             -  npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

             - ng build --prod
             - cp app.yaml dist
             - ls dist
             - cd dist

             - curl -o /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-190.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

             - tar -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz -C /tmp/

             - /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh -q

             - source /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
             - echo $GCLOUD_API_KEYFILE | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ./gcloud-api-key.json
             - gcloud config set project $GCLOUD_PROJECT

             - gcloud components install app-engine-java

             - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcloud-api-key.json

             - echo $GCLOUD_API_KEYFILE > /tmp/client-secret.json  

             - gcloud config set project $GCLOUD_PROJECT
             - gcloud app update --split-health-checks --project adtecy-ui 

             - gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

I am looking to use node docker image to deploy angular 5 (version 5.2.11) app to GAE flex environment but it takes an unusally long time and the status is still "In Progress" (not sure the usual deploy time)

This is my app.yaml file

```
    env: flex
    runtime: python


    threadsafe: true

    readiness_check:

       timeout_sec: 4
       check_interval_sec: 5
       failure_threshold: 2
       success_threshold: 2
       app_start_timeout_sec: 3600
```

I have given a very high timeout period because the previous push failed with a timeout

I believe GAE by default use python and hence we did not install python
Right now the deployment is running for about 20 mins or so but without letting us know any result. Could you guys help in deploying my app to GAE with minimal time?

EDIT:
Now we have got the result after running for 33 minutes
        `21df82f90a72: Layer already exists

```
    aeb4b6656589: Pushed

    latest: digest: 

sha256:c57d3178321c5f2721fc70cd00cb7862d469c74a6bf616ecfda760342c13af7e size: 3255

    DONE
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...
    .failed.
     ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Operation [apps/adtecy- 
     ui/operations/9c273f87-91a3-495a-b75d-0d6c767dce97] timed out. 
     This operation may still be underway.`
```

Comment: You are not supposed to mix nodejs runtime with Python as you do in the `app.yaml` file. GAE doesn't use Python by default, it has runtimes for different languages. Look at the example in [this link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/hello-world/flexible/app.yaml). The `app.yaml` should be like this in the first lines:


`runtime: nodejs
env: flex`

Try this change first and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status of the deploy operation by running

gcloud app operations "apps/adtecy-ui/operations/9c273f87-91a3-495a-b75d-0d6c767dce97"

Comment: Now since I use bitbucket pipeline, I will not have any mechansim to interact with the console. And moreover "9c273f87-91a3-495a-b75d-0d6c767dce97" is the operation that error that was reported for the previous run. So I believe I will not be able to add the above command since there will be new ID generated for the operation on a new run. Is there any other way to resolve this?

Comment: I was able to get that finally deployed and a GAE instance is currently serving but it is throwing "404 -The requested URL / was not found on this server" exception. Could you let me know your thoughts on this?

Comment: I tried to simulate the latency issue in local and I was able to replicate it with the different app.yaml files. But the operation command that you specified again  says that the health checks were not done on time and hence a timeout. Can you suggest a way to successfully access link in GAE

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be an issue with running the app is nodejs environment. So I switched to python27 and I was able to successfully deploy it. But when I try to load using the app served in GAE it is throwing an error.

https://adtecy-ui.appspot.com

And here is my app.yaml (And I made some modifications too)

```
    runtime: python27
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: true



    handlers:
    # Routing for bundles to serve directly
    - url: /((?:inline|main|polyfills|styles|vendor)\.[a-z0-9]+\.bundle\.js)
      secure: always
      redirect_http_response_code: 301
      static_files: dist/\1
      upload: dist/.*

      # Routing for a prod styles.bundle.css to serve directly
      - url: /(styles\.[a-z0-9]+\.bundle\.css)
        secure: always
        redirect_http_response_code: 301
        static_files: dist/\1
        upload: dist/.*

        # Routing for typedoc, assets and favicon.ico to serve directly
        - url: /((?:assets|docs)/.*|favicon\.ico)
         secure: always
         redirect_http_response_code: 301
         static_files: dist/\1
         upload: dist/.*


         # Any other requests are routed to index.html for angular to 
         handle so we don't need hash URLs
         - url: /.*
           secure: always
           redirect_http_response_code: 301
           static_files: dist/index.html
           upload: dist/index\.html
```

Comment: The error is a 404 - The requested URL / was not found on this server. So if anyone can shed some light on it, it would be helpful as I am struggling to get it working